# How to select all records of from a collection using wildcard?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I want to use a wildcard in a query to select all records from a collection.

I have tried to use `*` and `%` as a wildcard for matching zero or all characters.
But it doesn't work.

```py
from pymongo import MongoClient
import datetime

client = MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
database = client["local"]
collection = database["someDB"]

if flag = True:
    ch = "Pass"
else:
    ch = "*"

query = {}
query["Current Stage"] = ch

cursor = collection.find(query)
try:
    for doc in cursor:
        print(doc)
finally:
    client.close()
```

It was expected that all entries from the collection come up when the `Flag` is `False`. I have tried `"*"` and `"%"` as matching character.

Comment: That was all I needed. Regex answers to my problem. Thanks for pointing out the Regex option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could perhaps try a regular expression? With RegEx you can use a dot (.) as a wildcard when you know the number of characters and backslash dot ( /.) when you don't know the number of characters, which you could use in your code. 
https://regexone.com/lesson/wildcards_dot 
(Sorry, don't have enough rep for a comment)

Comment: Regex solves the problem. Thanks. You will climb up soon on reps.